# How to add checkbox when I select a dropdown list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want pop-up message box.when I add some day or week and number of day or week in integer format. when I click on submit button that time i selected values goes on main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple pop-up message box example link :

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp